# xen-create-image does not create inird or initramfs image and domU does not starts with system image

Tags: xen, fedora

I have Fedora 19 as Dom0. To create image I run

`# xen-create-image --hostname=debian-wheezy --memory=512Mb --dhcp --size=20Gb --swap=512Mb --dir=/xen --arch=amd64 --dist=wheezy`

After generation finished I start vm and see:

```
# xl create /etc/xen/debian-wheezy.cfg
Parsing config from /etc/xen/debian-wheezy.cfg
libxl: error: libxl_dom.c:409:libxl__build_pv: xc_dom_ramdisk_file failed: No such file or directory
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:919:domcreate_rebuild_done: cannot (re-)build domain: -3
```

In the /etc/xen/debian-wheezy.cfg i have

```
#
#  Kernel + memory size
#
kernel      = '/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.2-201.fc19.x86_64'
ramdisk     = '/boot/initrd.img-3.11.2-201.fc19.x86_64'
```

and `ls -1 /boot/*201*` shows

```
/boot/config-3.11.2-201.fc19.x86_64
/boot/initramfs-3.11.2-201.fc19.x86_64.img
/boot/System.map-3.11.2-201.fc19.x86_64
/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.2-201.fc19.x86_64
```

Then if I fix `ramdisk` directive in .cfg file to `/boot/initramfs-3.11.2-201.fc19.x86_64.img` vm will start but os inside will not boot. In a tail of xl console I get

```
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
dracut-initqueue[130]: Warning: Could not boot.
dracut-initqueue[130]: Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/085883ad-73ca-45cc-8bc5-e6249f869b26 does not exist
dracut-initqueue[130]: Warning: /dev/fedora/root does not exist
dracut-initqueue[130]: Warning: /dev/fedora/swap does not exist
dracut-initqueue[130]: Warning: /dev/mapper/fedora-root does not exist
dracut-initqueue[130]: Warning: /dev/mapper/fedora-swap does not exist
dracut-initqueue[130]: Warning: /dev/xvda2 does not exist
Starting Dracut Emergency Shell...
Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/085883ad-73ca-45cc-8bc5-e6249f869b26 does not exist
Warning: /dev/fedora/root does not exist
Warning: /dev/fedora/swap does not exist
Warning: /dev/mapper/fedora-root does not exist
Warning: /dev/mapper/fedora-swap does not exist
Warning: /dev/xvda2 does not exist

Generating "/run/initramfs/sosreport.txt"


Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
You might want to save "/run/initramfs/sosreport.txt" to a USB stick or /boot
after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.


dracut:/#
```

.img files in `/xen/domains/debian-wheezy` exists and listed in *disk* section of debian-wheezy.cfg

So what should i do?

**Update:**

I've found that xl does not mount images. In debian-wheezy.cfg I have that:

```
root        = '/dev/xvda2 ro'
disk        = [
                  'file:/xen/domains/debian-wheezy/disk.img,xvda2,w',
                  'file:/xen/domains/debian-wheeze/swap.img,xvda1,w',
              ]
```

And there is no /dev/xvda* or /dev/sda* or /dev/hda* files in VM.

Comment: You're creating a paravirtualized machine this way, which is kind of deprecated, especially since the CPU vulnerabilities. Look into making HVM machines. I don't know if virt-manager is magic (we don't use it), but we make machines by downloading Ubuntu Cloud images and making a CD ISO files as 'data source' for initial configuration, which are read by 'cloud init'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `virt-manager` to create/manage your VMs.